# lists without iterator in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's say there is a forward linked list:

```
public class A
{
    public B Next { get; set; }

    public String Value { get; set; }

    public A(string value, B next)
    {
        this.Next = next;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

public class B
{
    public A Next { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public B(int value, A next)
    {
        this.Next = next;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

public partial class MyWindow : Window
{

    public A My_List{ get; set; }

    public MyWindow()
    {
        Program program = new Program();

        this.My_List = new A("value1", new B(1, new A("Value2", new B(2, new A("value3", new B(3, null))))));

        this.DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

How can I show the *My_List* in Wpf?
I tried:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WpfApplication2:A}" x:Key="A_Template">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Value}" />
                <Label Content="---" />
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Next.Value}" />
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Next.Next}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource A_Template}">

                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <ItemsControl   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=My_List}"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource A_Template}">

        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

But it does not work, I think it is because *My_List* has to be a actual list and not the first element.

Edit: There is just an empty window, no output, no compiler error an no runtime exception.

Comment: do you see any errors in the output log (if you're using Visual Studio)? What happends if you implement the `GetEnumerator()` method in `A` (similar to `yield next` or something like that)

Comment: or create a property that returns `IEnumerable<>` of your items and let that property traverse the linked list. [The `ItemsSource` binds to an IEnumerator<>.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx)

Comment: But then I treat them the same, I want two different classes...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The `ItemsSource` has to be bound to something that returns `IEnumerable<>` otherwise, it cannot enumerate the objects.

Comment: Ok, but say I want a different *DataTemplate* for objects of class *B*. Is it still possible using an Enumerator? But I'm feeling like it is not possible to present a list without an Enumerator in Wpf.

Comment: By the way, you might want to use the [LinkedList<T> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx)? Of course, it does implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I show the *My_List* in Wpf?

If you want to use `A` as an `ItemsSource` for `ItemsControl`, then you have to implement `IEnumerable` in `A` like this:

```
public class A : IEnumerable
{
    public B Next { get; set; }

    public String Value { get; set; }

    public A(string value, B next)
    {
        this.Next = next;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    #region IEnumerable Members

    private class AEnumerator : IEnumerator
    {
        private readonly A head;

        public AEnumerator(A head)
        {
            this.head = head;
        }

        #region IEnumerator Members

        public object Current { get; private set; }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (Current == null)
            {
                Current = head;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Current.GetType() == typeof(A))
                {
                    Current = ((A)Current).Next;
                }
                else
                {
                    Current = ((B)Current).Next;
                }
            }

            return Current != null;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new AEnumerator(this);
    }

    #endregion
}
```